# Zend Framework 2 - Including a variable in a form action

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

My login form may be called with a re-direct query and I am wondering if there is a simple way to include this in the subsequent post action.

The use case is for SSO login.

**My normal login route is:**

```
/customer/login
```

**and when called from a third party client becomes:**

```
/customer/login?redirectTo=http://www.example.com
```

**My login action:**

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $prg = $this->prg();

    if ($prg instanceof Response) {
        return $prg;
    } elseif ($prg === false) {
        return new ViewModel(['form' => $this->loginForm]);
    }
```

This loads my view and I currently define my action as so:

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url());
```

Now when the action is called, I am losing the redirectTo parameter.

So my question is this, is it possible to update the action to include the re-direct url so that when a user clicks to login, it is posted back to my form?

thanks!

EDIT - 
Obviously I can create a redirectTo route in the configs and test on the initial call to the page for the existence of such a route and include this in the form. My question however is whether or not this can be done automagically simply from the viewscript.

Comment: The code I showed you creates the url inside the view file. Why would you touch the route configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate query string arguments from the view helper, you need to assign them as the third argument using the query key. Please refer to the ZF2 docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('application', array('action' => 'login'), array('query' => array('redirectTo' => 'http://www.example.com,))));
```

Comment: This will work if I am grabbing the redirect url from the controller and sending to the view. I am however wondering if it is possible to skip that step...

Comment: No that I'm aware of. You must do it from the controller. That's why there are view helpers.

Answer (score 0):

`$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('login', [
       'query' => [
            'redirectTo' => $this->params()->fromQuery('redirectTo')
        ]
    ]);`

Where 'login' is the name of the login route.

See [Url View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html)

Comment: I dont think this will work in a view: $this->params()

Answer (score 0):

Well my solution is not as elegant as I hoped it would be. I wanted to avoid using the controller for the query params. As @Stanimir pointed out, the view helpers are in fact, to help with view so my original idea was unfounded.

This is an end to end of what I have put together:

**Controller:**

```
 $redirect_url = $this->params()->fromQuery('redirectTo',null);
```

Returns this to view on initial load:

```
return new ViewModel( ['form' => $this->loginForm , 'redirect_url' => $redirect_url] );
```

**View**

```
$form->setAttribute(
     'action', 
     $this->url( 
         'customer/login', [] , 
         [ 'query'=> 
              [ 'redirectTo' => $this->redirect_url ] 
         ] 
      ) 
 );
```